# ASP.Net xml web service properties returning null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cryptography

I have a traditional Xml web service on my web Server.It has a service call Main Service.Overview of Class is given below.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MainService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    private byte[] symmetricKey;
    private byte[] symmetricIv;

    public byte[] SymmetricKey
    {

        get { return symmetricKey; }
        set { symmetricKey = value; }
    }
    public byte[] SymmetricIv
    {
        get { return symmetricIv; }
        set { symmetricIv = value; }
    }

    //Constructor

    public MainService()
    {
        this.GetDatabaseInstance();
    }

//Some Web Methods Heare to create the Symmetric Key
}
```

In my Client i have a method where i have following cording

```
MainService mainService=new MainsService();

//Calling to Some web method to create symmetric keys and assign those properties

//Now trying to access those properties

var key=mainService.SymmetricKey;
```

Variable "key" was getting null values when i accessing that.But i debugged the Web service class.  Private variables  were getting values.Why values are not coming on the Client code?May be properties were setting reference without setting values?Because i can access the variable values by returning an OUT variable through the web method? Can any one please explain the answer?

Following method  is the web method Which was creating Keys

```
    [WebMethod]
    //create a symmetric key and encript it using clients public key and return values
    public bool CreateKeys(byte[] exponent, byte[] modulus)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class.
            var rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            //Create a new instance of the RSAParameters structure.
            RSAParameters rsaKeyInfo = new RSAParameters();

            //Set RSAKeyInfo to the public key values. 
            rsaKeyInfo.Modulus = modulus;
            rsaKeyInfo.Exponent = exponent;

            //Import key parameters into RSA.
            rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(rsaKeyInfo);

            //Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class.
            var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndaelManaged.GenerateKey();
            rijndaelManaged.GenerateIV();

            //save  the symmetric key and IV
            SymmetricKey = rijndaelManaged.Key;
            SymmetricIv = rijndaelManaged.IV;

            //Encrypt the symmetric key and IV.
            encryptedSymmetricKey = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(rijndaelManaged.Key, false);
            encryptedSymmetricIv = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(rijndaelManaged.IV, false);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In you Client you are using the wrong case for the proeprty it should be SymmetricKey

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake on posting question.I edited now.Actual code is like you said.

Comment: Please can you show the code in your service how does SymmetricKey gets its value assigned

Answer (score 1):

In you client code you are using `var key=mainService.symmetricKey;`

But symmetricKey is private `byte[]` and cannot be accessed outside its contianing type. So you will have to use the `public property SymmetricKey` like this

```
var key=mainService.SymmetricKey;
```

Update :

The line I doubt is causing the issue must be this one

```
        SymmetricKey = rijndaelManaged.Key;
```

also the catch block inside the CreateKeys method buble up exception by throw;

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake on posting question.I edited now.Actual code is like you said.

Comment: Please can you put a break point in the catch block of CreateKeys method and check if any error get caught